# ¿Cómo conocer cantidad de descargas en lanzamientos y repositorios de github?

Tags: github

¿Como puedo saber cuantas descargas ha tenido un lanzamiento en mi repositorio de github? y¿cuantas descargas o clonaciones ha tenido el repositorio?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la API de Github como el siguiente link:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<Usuario GitHub>/<Repositorio GitHub>/releases
```

Para el ejemplo utilicé este repo:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/Inori/GPCS4/releases
```

La respuesta que obtienes es un JSON:

```
"content_type": "application/octet-stream",
        "state": "uploaded",
        "size": 1120767,
        "download_count": 4216,
        "created_at": "2020-02-06T08:07:12Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-02-06T08:07:16Z",
        "browser_download_url": "https://github.com/Inori/GPCS4/releases/download/v0.10/GPCS4.7z"
```

Comment: ¿La clave "download_count" corresponde a la descarga del lanzamiento o a las clonaciones del repositorio?, dependiendo de la respuesta, ¿como consigo el contador para lo otro?

Comment: A las descargas del repo. Pensé que en la etiqueta `Insights` dentro del repo había información sobre las clonaciones pero no veo por ninguna parte.